# pandas - automate graph using the combination of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, graph

What is the best way to automate the graph production in the following case:

- I have a data frame with different plan and type in the columns
- I want a graph for each combination of plan and type

Dataframe:

```
plan type  hour  ok    notok  other 
A    cont   0    60.0  40.0    0.0    
A    cont   1    56.6  31.2    12.2    
A    vend   2    30.0  50.0    20.0    
B    test   5    20.0  50.0    30.0
```

For one df with only one plan and type, I wrote the following code:

```
fig_ = df.set_index('hour').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, colormap='YlOrBr')
plt.xlabel('Hour')
plt.ylabel('(%)')
fig_.figure.savefig('p_hour.png', dpi=1000)
plt.show()
```

In the end, I would like to save one different figure for each combination of plan and type.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [iterating over groups](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups) using `groupby`:

```
for (plan, type), group in df.groupby(['plan', 'type']):
    fig_ = group.set_index('hour').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, colormap='YlOrBr')
    plt.xlabel('Hour')  # Maybe add plan and type
    plt.ylabel('(%)')  # Maybe add plan and type
    fig_.figure.savefig('p_hour_{}_{}.png'.format(plan, type), dpi=1000)
```